# Невзирая на то(,) что

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`Невзирая на то(,) что лил-таки дождёнок, я пошёл в магазинчик.`

А здесь? (Без ударения на *невзирая*.)

`Я пошёл в магазин, невзирая на то(,) что лил дождь.`

А если я акцент делаю на *невзирая*, то первая запятая не нужна, то бишь так надо писать?

`Я пошёл в магазин невзирая на то, что лил дождь.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка знаков **факультативна:**  расчленение союза зависит от структуры предложения, позиции придаточного, а также авторского акцентирования:

(1) ***Невзирая на то что лил-таки дождёнок**, // я пошёл в магазинчик.*

(2) *Я пошёл в магазИн, // **невзирая на то что лил дОждь**.*

При отсутствии акцентирования выбор делается с учетом **структуры** предложения. В данном случае предложение нераспространенное, поэтому нет  необходимости в расчленении союза (при любой позиции придаточного).

(3) Акцентирование придаточного возможно при расчленении союза по **первому** варианту (придаточное предложение перед главным):

***Невзирая на тО**, что лил дождь, я пошёл в магазИн.*

**Примечание.** Придаточное предложение отделяется запятой всегда, акцентирование влияет только на расчленение союза.

Comment: А если я ударение на на *магазин*, а на *невзирая на то* ставлю?

Comment: Это вариант (3). Расчленение придаточного предложения  в начале главного подчеркивает значимость придаточного. Вообще говоря, союз - это показатель зависимости придаточного от главного, Если он не расчленен, то такая зависимость ясно обозначена: вот главное, а вот зависимое. При расчленении союза местоименная часть союза (невзирая на то) входит в главное предложение, у него ударная позиция.  Тогда мы получаем взаимообусловленность, и  значимость придаточного повышается.

Comment: Леопольд, видимо, спрашивает о варианте 3: *Я пошёл в магазин невзирая на тО, что лил дождь.* Ставится ли запятая перед "невзирая"?

Comment: Хотите запятую поставить?  Известная история....  Я против, в вы?

Comment: Я не хочу. Недавно говорили об этом союзе, что Грамота всегда ставит две запятые (перед и внутри). Почему-то "несмотря на то что" повезло больше :)): ему позволено не расчленяться и слово "обычно" добавлено насчёт запятой перед ним.

Comment: Вот и я не хочу,  так как не понимаю такую грамматику.  По какому случаю делим структуру предложения на две части? Я "догадываюсь", в чем тут дело, они видят в таком предложении местоименную и изъяснительную часть в отдельности. Представьте, что я расчленю союз  следствия ТАК ЧТО пополам. Низзя?  Другая грамматика? А здесь, значит, можно?  А если еще запятую перед КАК поставлю? УжОс!

Comment: Так можно ли писать «Я пошёл в магазин невзирая на то, что лил дождь»?

Comment: Грамота вроде бы разрешает две запятые: Я пошёл в магазин, невзирая на то, что лил дождь?  Не знаю, какую грамматику они при этом имеют в виду.  Лошадь начинала уставать, а с него пот катился градом, несмотря на то, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу. А. Пушкин, Метель. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483

Answer (score 0):

Нет, тут обязательна запятая. Могла бы не ставиться, если после *что* шло бы существительное. Если после *что* идёт глагол, то речь идёт о действии, и получается конфликт деепричастия и действия. Кроме того последующая часть должна быть обстоятельством места или еще чего-то, но не действия.

То есть:

Невзирая на то что дождик поливал улицу, я пошёл в магазинчик.

Но:

Невзирая на то, что поливал дождик, я пошёл в магазинчик.

Вот тексты [Булгарина](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqGAoICA8QChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJwolCiMKA3JlcRIcChrQvdC10LLQt9C40YDQsNGPINC90LAg0YLQvjAB#:%7E:text=%D0%A4.%20%D0%92.%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD.%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%20%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%20(1829)), можете ознакомиться.

Comment: Так то же когда было... Грамматическое детство.  Булгарин не знал даже, что такое сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП), это понятие ввел Н.И. Греч в книге «Практическая русская грамматика» (1834).

Comment: Для меня конфликт есть между деепричастием и глаголом, мне не так важно знал Булгарин или нет, у него это звучит, тут это не звучит. Тем более, что лил дождёнок - это не обстоятельство, а простое предложение в составе сложного.

Comment: лил дождь - это простое предложение. Простые предложения могут входить в состав деепричастного оборота? Я сомневаюсь в этом.

Comment: Это придаточное предложение, но "несмотря на" и "невзирая на" - это уже предлоги, но не деепричастия. Хотя лил дождь...

Comment: невзирая на льющийся дождь было бы тогда. У вас получается, что предлоги диктуют семантику. А предлоги - это служебные части речи, они не определяют значения фразы после, но вводят некоторые логические аспекты.

Comment: У вас обстоятельственный оборот: вопреки дождю.

Comment: Да, поэтому я и говорю, что дождь должно стоять первым, но и этого не достаточно, потому что дождь лучше дополнить адекватным обстоятельством где дождь, какой дождь. Вопреки "лил" - это уже совсем другая история. Несмотря на то что я вышел на улицу, лил дождь - вот так)

Comment: Все это должно соответствовать грамматике, как ее понимают лингвисты, причем специалисты именно по синтаксису, а не по пунктуации. А ваше понимание не укладывается в грамматические модели СПП.

Comment: Мне нравится ваша последняя фраза, она абсолютно бессодержательна. Язык никому не должен) Грамматика языка должна быть понятна, любому, не только лингвисту, специалисту или синтаксисту. Ист, кстати, суффикс идеологического учения), идеологи.

Comment: А у вас содержательное?))  Грамматика языка кому должна? Лично вам?)

Comment: должны быть понятна, а не должна кому-то или чему-то. Но так как я пишу, мне очевидно должно быть понятно, что написано, об чём, так сказать, речь: о дожде или обо мне?

Comment: Не вижу разницы, все равно должна. Вас много, а она одна (если это научная грамматика).

Comment: Хорошо. Ладно, я сказал: лил дождь - это простое предложение в лучшем случае, не обстоятельство и не обстоятельный оборот. Добавление предлогов сути не меняет

Comment: Невзирая на то, что поливал дождик, я пошёл в магазинчик. Сколько здесь простых предложений/предикативных основ?

Comment: https://old.bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/3174985 я бы не использовал словосочетание предикативная основа, мне оно не кажется корректным. Однако предикативность поливал дождик и пошёл в магазинчик неравнозначны, даже больше от поливал дождик зависит время когда я пошел в магазинчик. Невзирая на то, что поливал дождик, я пошёл в магазинчик. Невзирая на то, что поливает дождик, я пошёл в магазинчик. Получается дождик диктует время, когда я пошел в магазинчик, то есть предикативность в поливал, поэтому он должен быть отделен запятой)

Comment: Кстати, разница между поливал дождик и дождик поливал может еще быть выражена так: Невзирая на то что дождик поливает, я пошёл в магазинчик. Я пошёл в магазинчик, а дождик поливает. В случае с поливал в начале получается странная несвязанная фраза, либо незаконченная: я пошел в магазинчик, а поливает дождик. А лил дождик - звучит еще более стремно) как набор несогласованных впечатлений: я пошёл в магазинчик; а лил дождик.